# Complex numbers, 1-1, onto

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Define $\mathbb R^+_0 = \{x \in \mathbb  R | x \ge 0\}$.
Consider each of the following functions.

$f\colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb R\times\mathbb R$

$g \colon \mathbb R^+_0 \times [0,2\pi) \to \mathbb C$

$h \colon \mathbb C\to\mathbb D$

$p \colon \mathbb C\to \mathbb R^+_0 $

$f(z)=(\operatorname{Re}(z),\operatorname{Im}(z))$

$g(r,θ)=r(\cosθ+i\sinθ)$.

$h(z) = iz - z^*$ (where $z^*$ means z conjugate)

$p(z)=|z+i|$.

```
(a) List all functions above that are 1-1. 
(b) List all functions above that are onto.
```

How can I determine which is which?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Only f, and g are 1-1.

b) f, g, and p are onto.

Comment: so h is neither?

Comment: @user136088:yes